# Cannot Filter Locations In Flutter

Tags: loops, flutter, dart, iteration

I am trying to filter out locations in my flutter application. I can filter my markers but, I'm not sure what the best way to pull the locations by name details. Here is how I'm creating markers:

```html
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};


  Future filterMarker(_userlat, _userlong) async {
    int filterCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < venues.length; ++i) {
      Geolocator()
          .distanceBetween(
              _userLat, _userlong, venues[i].latitude, venues[i].longitude)
          .then((calcDist) {
        if (calcDist / 1000 < 1) {
          filterCounter++;
          placeFilteredMarker(filterCounter, calcDist / 1000, venues[i].name,
              venues[i].latitude, venues[i].longitude);

          filtervenues(filterCounter, venues[i].name, venues[i].address,
              venues[i].rating, calcDist / 1000);
        }
      });
    }
  }


  placeFilteredMarker(counter, distance, name, lat, lng) {
    final int markerCount = counter;

    for (int i = 0; i < markerCount; i++) {
      final String markerIdVal = 'marker_id_$markerCount';

      final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

      // creating a new MARKER
      final Marker marker = Marker(
        markerId: markerId,
        position: LatLng(lat, lng),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: name, snippet: '$distance'),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
      );

      setState(() {
        markers[markerId] = marker;
        // adding a new marker to map
      });

      return;
    }
  }
```

I'm trying something similar with a list of details. Filtering by location and showing the details but, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here is what I'm trying

Here is the issue: I'm not sure what I should do to pull out Name,address, and rating.

```html
List<Venue>venue;  
  
  Future filterMarker(_userlat, _userlong) async {
    int filterCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < venues.length; ++i) {
      Geolocator()
          .distanceBetween(
              _userLat, _userlong, venues[i].latitude, venues[i].longitude)
          .then((calcDist) {
        if (calcDist / 1000 < 1) {
          filterCounter++;
          placeFilteredMarker(filterCounter, calcDist / 1000, venues[i].name,
              venues[i].latitude, venues[i].longitude);

          filtervenues(filterCounter, venues[i].name, venues[i].address,
              venues[i].rating, calcDist / 1000);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  
  
  filtervenues(counter, name, addres, rating, distance) {
    final int venueCounter = counter;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < venueCounter; i++) {
      setState(() {


      });
      return;
    }
  }
```

That should iterate and then add to the container below:

```html
  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, _name, _address, _rating) {
  
    return Container(
      height: 425,
      child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 2,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 2,
                ),
                _locations(venues[index].name, venues[index].address,
                    venues[index].rating),
                Divider(
                  height: 2,
                )
              ],
            );
          ),
    );
  }
```

Photo update. I am trying to put the data that the markers have into this bottom sheet.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Are you using google maps flutter?

Comment: Yes. I'm using google maps flutter plug in

Comment: And the Container shall go into a Listview, or do you simply want a List of Containers? Additionally what is _locations?

Comment: I'll update the code with a screenshot in a few moments. _locations is a bottomsheet where the info will be displayed in more details. But yes, the markers can go into a list the google map.

Comment: Added photo to show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Gonna Look into it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: This whole logic seems to be pretty unperformant. You are setting State on each iteration of the for loop, which causes the MapsWidget to rebuild each iteration. Why don't you create a List of Marker Items and then in the end do smth like in the following code. Additionaly i would do the something similar to the Venues:

```dart
class Location {
   final Venue venue;
   final double dist;
   final int index;
   Location({this.venue, this.dist, this.index});
}
```

```dart
  Set<Marker> markers = Set(); //Google Maps Markers are normally a Set
  List<Location> location = List();


  Future filterMarker(_userlat, _userlong) async {
    Set<Marker> _tmpMarkers = Set();
    int filterCounter = 0;
    List<Location> _tmpLocation = List();
    for (int i = 0; i < venues.length; ++i) {
      Geolocator()
          .distanceBetween(
              _userLat, _userlong, venues[i].latitude, venues[i].longitude)
          .then((calcDist) {
        if (calcDist / 1000 < 1) {
          filterCounter++;
          final String markerIdVal = 'marker_id_$filterCounter';

          final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

         // creating a new MARKER
         tmpMarkers.add(Marker(
           markerId: markerId,
           position: LatLng(venues[i].latitude, venues[i].longitude),
           infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: venues[i].name, snippet: '$calcDist / 1000'),
           icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
          ));
          _tmpLocation.add(Location(index: i, Venue: venue[i], dist: calcDist / 1000));
        }
      });
    }
    setState((){
     markers = _tmpMarkers;
     location = _tmpLocation;
    });
  }
```

Then you use your Location Object in the bottom sheet. Furthermore I was not able to test this code as I don't have your full code, perhaps there are some brackets missing.

Then you can use the location list in a ListView.builder in the bottomSheet.
There you can style each List tile yourself.

```
// As you didn't provide any code of your bottom sheet i just call it DraggableBottomSheet
bottomSheet: DraggableBottomSheet(
   child: Column(
    children : [
      Row(
        children: [
           Text('bla'),
           Text(location.length.toString(),
             ]
        ),
      ListView.builder(
          itemCount: location.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return Container(
                 child Column(
                     children : [
                          Text(location[index].venue.name),
                          Text(location[index].dist.toString()),
                       ]
                 )
              );
            }
        )
     ]
   )
)
```